# What is the worst case when the epmd port is open?

Tags: erlang

When using Erlang programs like [ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/) the [Erlang port mapper daemon](http://linux.die.net/man/1/epmd) `epmd` is started and opens port `4369`.

This port is accessible over the internet (only most recent ejabberd versions allow to configure that epmd should bind to localhost) by default.

The ejabberd documentation recommends [blocking this port via packet filter rules](http://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html#htoc81) and a [comment in the Debian bug tracker](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=585122) calls this default behavior 'a nightmare from a security point of view'.

What is the worst case scenario when ejabberd is running and port `4369` is not blocked?

Say - the firewall is mis-configured by accident or something like that.

What would be the most evil thing a Erlang-fluent attacker could do over this port?

Under what user/privileges runs the `epmd` under a linux distribution (e.g. Debian/Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find out the source/destination addresses and port number pairs of active connections between BEAMs. This may lead into DoS attacks to the inter-BEAM connections.

Comment: I guess a BEAM is an something like a process in Erlang?

Comment: BEAM is a virtual machine. BEAM initiates and receives TCP connections for inter-BEAM connections. So it's not an Erlang process, but is indeed a Linux or UNIX program running as the Linux of UNIX process.

Answer (score 7):

Great question.

Besides port 4369 you also have to take into account the ports it will suggest for the actual inter-node communication (5001-6024 by default). Like all tcp services it will be vulnerable to evil-doers, as software is never bug free thus hackable. Think SSH and it's buffer overflow vulnerabilities. As 'epmd' doesn't provide a lot of services, internode communication is authenticated with a secure cookie code and the relative old age of Erlang you would expect not a lot of bugs in that area. But a good pedigree alone doesn't count in the security area. ;-)

As you wrote, you need a properly configured firewall to make sure the server is not exposed like that. You need to make sure in your maintenance process that proper functioning of the firewall is thoroughly checked.

Oh, and I run my Erlang node as non-root user with limited file permissions.